# How to build c3js line diagram from some function, not just simple array with random numbers?

Tags: javascript, diagram, c3.js

I need to build a line diagram of some function (for example y=x*x). But how to pass the values of x and y to C3 columns?

Here I have the code, that build just a simple line diagram, so how do I need to modify it?

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    xs: {
        'data1': 'x1',
        'data2': 'x2',
    },
    columns: [
        ['x1', 10, 30, 45, 50, 70, 100],
        ['x2', 30, 50, 75, 100, 120],
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 20, 180, 240, 100, 190]
    ]
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just calculating some values and pushing it to your diagram? You only need one loop, calculate your data and push the results to the column.
For example:

```
var functionDataY = ['yLabel']
var functionDataX = ['xLabel']

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  functionDataY.push(i*i);
  functionDataX.push(i);
}

var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    xs: {
        'yLabel': 'xLabel',
    },
    columns: [
        functionDataY, functionDataX
    ]
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's helpfull